# How can I use .htpasswd across my entire site?

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, .htpasswd

How can I use my .htpasswd login "session" all across my site?
I want to be able to login to via /admin.php using my .htpasswd account, then display certain admin features on other pages, ex. /browse.php, if the admin is logged in.

Here's what I tried, which didn't work.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]) && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] == "admin") {
    $reportLink = "<a href=\"browse.php?url=" . $url . "&amp;report=" . $site_id . "\" style=\"color: #FFFFFF;\">Report Dead Link?</a>";

    if($_GET["report"] == $site_id && preg_match("/^\d+$/", $site_id) && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] == "admin") {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `websites` SET `status` = '4' WHERE `id` = '$site_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: browse.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: anotherpage.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your other pages are password protected under the same scheme, then the browser will re-submit the auth details for each one.

You know, [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) are far more flexible for this kind of thing...

Comment: Agreed.  Once you authenticate to get admin.php, set a flag in the session, and check that on other pages.